# Using AWK: Assign different number of concatenated fields to a variable

Tags: awk

Really sorry if this has been asked before as it feels basic, I'm just not connecting the dots and it's making me tear my hair out!

Essentially I have a text file , and I'm assigning the second field of particular rows to a variable i.e

```
VAR=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' entry.txt)
```

However, sometimes on row one in the text file, it will have 4 fields. I would like to say

```
   If ROW 1 has 4 fields  
        VAR = $2, $3 & $4 concatenated
   Else
        VAR = $2
```

I'm sure this is basic awk, I'm just undertaking a small project and have never used it before. I know i should read a book, but this really is a tiny script!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NF == 4 { print $2 $3 $4; exit } { print $2; exit }' file
```

This concatenates the second, third and fourth fields if there are exactly four whitespace-delimited fields on the first line of the file.  Otherwise, it will return the second field from  the first line of the file.  The program exits as soon as it has outputted anything, so we are certain that it's only the first line that we'll ever see.

With different logic:

```
awk 'NF == 4 { out = $2 $3 $4 } NF != 4 { out = $2 } { print out; exit }' file
```

or,

```
awk '{ out = $2 } NF == 4 { out = out $3 $4 } { print out; exit }' file
```

Either of these commands goes inside your command substitution:

```
var=$( awk ... )
```

Comment: Thank you, even simply seeing these examples helped me understand my small syntax errors that  ultimately lead to the hair-pulling!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1 && NF==4 { var=$2 $3 $4 } NR==1 && NF!=4 { var=$2 }' /path/to/input
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful in understanding how to apply the problem to any row of a file

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
awk '{$1=""; print (NF==4)?$0:$2; exit}' OFS= infile
```

The Ternary condition operator `(NF==4)?$0:$2` checks if the **N**umber of **F**ields were equal with 4 (when fields are separated with whitespaces (*awk* default *FS*) ) then print the whole line `$0` after we striping the first field `$1=""` else `:` print filed#2 `$2`.